# i am having problems building my nativescript app in the cloud with nativescript sidekick

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, nativescript

when i use Nativescript Sidekick to build my android app, i get and error which is

```
[19-05-21 14:50:42.551] Build failed. TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 3221225477
```

Please can you help me with this, or is there any other alternative

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5382 this is the first result I've found in google, did you check this already?

Comment: @briosheje i just check it out, it seems this error problem is happening to other nativescript users